# How to use Cassandra CLI on node.JS project?

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra nodeJS module using

```
$ npm install cassandra-driver
```

My project has the following structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvArq.png)

Given this structure how can I use terminal and Cassandra 'cqlsh' to perform tasks connected with database management?

Answer (score 3):

The node cassandra-driver is a [client driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#datastax-nodejs-driver-for-apache-cassandra) meant for interacting with Cassandra programmatically. It does not provide cqlsh.

cqlsh is the command line utility that gets [installed with Cassandra](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.4/bin/cqlsh). To use it you can visit a server where it is installed, or get a copy locally by downloading and unpacking a [release tarball](https://cassandra.apache.org/download/) (get a version matching the server to which you intend to connect).

Alternatively, there are [projects](https://github.com/spiside/cqlsh) around that provide ways of getting cqlsh without the rest (although these are maybe not widely supported by the community).